# Problem with overloading a function for literal strings

Tags: c++, string, templates, specialization

I have a template function that handles rvalues arguments. The argument is supposed to expose a certian function. For those rvalues that do not have this function, I need to use template specialization to handle the exceptions. The problem I have is with string literals. Here's a short example of what I am trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
  template < class T > void foo (T && x)
  {
    x.baa();
  }
};

struct B{
    void baa(){
        cout << "I have baa()" << endl;
    };
};

template <> void
A::foo (std::string && x)
{
  cout << "I am a std::string, I don't have baa()" << endl;
};

template <> void
A::foo (char *&&x)
{
  cout << "I am a char* and I am sad because nobody ever calls me" << endl;
};


int
main ()
{
  A a;
  a.foo (B());
  a.foo (std::string ("test1"));
  
  a.foo ("test2"); // this line causes a compiler error
  
  return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile the snippet above, I get the following error

> main.cpp:16:7: error: request for member ‘baa’ in ‘x’, which is of non-class type ‘const char [6]’

16 |     x.baa();

Obviously the compiler is trying to apply the generic function rather than the specialization for char*. How can I write a specialization that captures literal strings of any length?

Comment: The compiler told you the type; write a function (or a template) that takes **that type**. Either `template <std::size_t N> foo(const char arg[N])` or `foo(const char*)`. Note, in both cases, the **const**.

Comment: @PeteBecker `foo(const char arg[N])` would need to be `foo(const char (&arg)[N])` instead. You can't pass an array by value, and `foo(const char arg[N])` will silently be treated the same as `foo(const char *arg)`, so if you want to pass in the actual array type, you have to pass it by reference.

Comment: C-string literal is an lvalue, while your specialization accepts rvalue reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `"test2"` literal is an lvalue, while `char *&&x` is an rvalue reference and cannot be bound to an lvalue.

Comment: I did not realize that until now! I now know how to fix my problem.